# How do jquery library implement the $("") in jquery-1.x.x.js source code?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Recently I begin to study the jquery, I feel confused how jquery library implement the **$**, I walked through the jquery source code and still cannot understand it.

Why  is **$( "#xid" )** equivalent to **getElementById("xid")**?

Could you please explain ***$*** for me according to the **source code of jquery**?

thanks.

Comment: jQuery uses the Sizzle selector engine. You can look at its entire source code right here: https://github.com/jquery/sizzle/blob/master/sizzle.js

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### Quick Answer

The `$` is simply a function name. To explain in simple words, it just mimics the DOM Selector.

```
function $(selector)
{
    if (selector[0] == "#")
        return document.getElementById(substr(selector, 1));
    else if (selector[0] == ".")
        return document.getElementsByClassName...
    else
        return document.getElementsByTagName...
}
```

Where the selector is something like `#hello`, the `selector[0]` depicts the first character, which is a `#` in this case. The `#` is used to denote an ID of an element. Similarly, `.` is used to denote a class name and others are for tags. Hope it is clear.

Comment: The tests of course aren't `selector[0]==='#'` but rather `selector[0]==='#' && selector[0].indexOf(" ")===-1 &&`. In fact, there's actually a regex.

Comment: I think JQuery uses `document.querySelector[All]` and a shim for that for older browsers.

Comment: I agree, I just said something like that. Moreover, that `selector[0]` doesn't work! `:P`

Comment: I am looking into the source code but I can't find where it handles the default case.

Comment: Again I am saying, this would be the end thingy. Not the exact stuff. :)

Answer (score 1):

jQuery does roughly this:

```
if (the selector is a dom object){
  wrap the dom object;
}
else if (the selector is a string){
  if (it starts with `<` and ends with `>`){
    assume this is HTML;
  }else{
    run a complex regex to classify the selector;
  }
  if (the selector is HTML){
    create a new DOM element and return;
  } else if (the selector is an ID selector and there is no context) {
    use document.getElementByID;
  } else {
    if there is no context, use the jQuery root as the context;
    jQuerify the context if neccessary and use context.find;
  }
}
if (the selector is a function){
  assume document.ready;
}
```

Basically, it handles special cases and delegates the rest to `$.fn.find`, which, in turn, delegates to `$.find`, which is where I got lost.

Answer (score 1):

This is a tricky thing. If the parameter to `$()` is a string that does not begin with '<' and does not contain a '>', it will be matched against this regex

```
/^(?:[^#<]*(<[\w\W]+>)[^>]*$|#([\w\-]*)$)/
```

In case of an id like `#myid` the resulting array would be

```
var match = ['#myid', undefined, 'myid']
```

so `match[1]` would be undefined. In that case, jQuery will immediately evaluate `getElementById(match[2])`

Source: jQuery-1.7.1 code

Answer (score 0):

```
document.getElementById('id'); //returns a HTML DOM Object
$('#id');  //returns a jQuery Object
```

For id selectors, jQuery uses the JavaScript function `document.getElementById()`, which is extremely efficient. When another selector is attached to the id selector, such as h2#pageTitle, jQuery performs an additional check before identifying the element as a match.

[source](http://api.jquery.com/id-selector/)

Answer (score 0):

The $ represents the jQuery Function, and is actually a shorthand alias for jQuery. (Unlike in most languages, the $ symbol is not reserved, and may be used as a variable name.) It is typically used as a selector (i.e. a function that returns a set of elements found in the DOM).

Answer (score 0):

A $ sign to define/access jQuery .

that means,

$ as a variable that is an alias for the jQuery object.

jQuery uses the $ sign as a shortcut for jQuery.

Some other JavaScript libraries also use the dollar sign for their functions.

The jQuery noConflict() method specifies a custom name (like jq), instead of using the dollar sign.

The following link will help you

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/